# Building analog representation out of digital lines in PulseView

Tags: analog, adc, dac, logic-analyzer

I am not sure if I am posting this in the right forum so if not, please let me know so I'll can post it somewhere else.

I want to monitor an analog signal but I only have a logic analyser at home, so I want to deconstruct it using an ADC in order for my analyser to read it. The software I use is PulseView and I want to combine my 8 digital signals in one analog one.

I know that PulseView has several decoders but I didn't found any that could help me for that task.

If you need more information to help me or any tips where I should post this, let me know and I'll be happy to modify my question.

Thanks

Comment: What rise time or f do you need and clock rates avail?  Why not a free audio scope on PC using sound card?

Comment: Using and audio scope is a good idea. I never thought about that thank you